# IONIC Capacitor Error Plugin Not installed

Tags: ionic-framework, nfc, capacitor

i'm trying to integrate nfc support to my ionic capacitor project. I followed this documentation:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc
I installed all required packages:

```
"@ionic-native/nfc": "^4.20.0",
"phonegap-nfc": "^1.2.0",
```

here is my app.module:

```
  providers: [
AuthGuard,
StatusBar,
ScreenOrientation,
SplashScreen,
InAppBrowser,
{provide: MAT_BOTTOM_SHEET_DATA, useValue: {}},
{provide: MatBottomSheetRef, useValue: {}},
NFC,
Ndef,
{provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy}
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]. 
 })
```

if i try to run it on ios, im running the following commands:

```
ionic build
npx cap sync
npx cap open ios
```

if i run i'm getting this error:

```
⚡️  [warn] - Install the NFC plugin: 'ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-nfc'
⚡️  [error] - ERROR plugin_not_installe
```

and here is my component code:

```
  readNFC() {
this.nfc.addNdefListener(() => {
  this.presentAlert('ok');
}, (err) => {
  this.presentAlert('ko' + err);
}).subscribe((event) => {
  console.log(event);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(event));

  this.presentAlert('Il messaggio contiene' + event.tag + ' ' + this.nfc.bytesToHexString(event.tag.id));
});
```

}

Comment: npm install phonegap-nfc 
npm install @ionic-native/nfc 
ionic cap sync

Comment: @RaviAshara unfortunately same error

Comment: I have the same issue, but with the @ionic-native/calendar plugin. Did you ever find a solution?